# Why cursor is not starting from the initial position in the input field

Tags: php, sql

In a form I have a input field like the following

```
echo "<input type='text' size='1' maxlength='2' id='dd{$i}' name='dd[$i]' value='$r1[C1S1]' 
onkeyup='if(this.value.length >=2) 
this.form.dd{$j}.focus();'/>
";
```

When I click in the input box, the cursor by default starts from the 2nd position (as a result its length becomes 2 with only one digit input), using backspace I have to bring it to the initial position.

If I omit the 'value' element, the problem solves. 
I cant make out where is the problem, why the cursor is not starting from the initial position.

Any idea please

Comment: Are you perhaps missing something in `$r1[C1S1]` (in the value attribute)?

Comment: what does $r1[C1S1] contains. you might have appending " " character to  $r1[C1S1] some where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first try with:

```
trim($r1[C1S1])
```

so instead of

```
value='$r1[C1S1]'
```

you should put here

```
value='".trim($r1[C1S1])."'
```

but you should also make sure that you have defined `C1S1` constant. If not, you should probably use here:

```
$r1['C1S1']
```

or

```
trim($r1['C1S1'])
```